# Running an "always-on" MQTT client from within a Gogole Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, google-compute-engine

Hello – I am new to Linux, and I have a few questions.

I have a Google Virtual Machine – running Linux.

On the VM, I have installed a Mosquitto MQTT broker, which has been running successfully for a few weeks – no problems.

Now I want to run an “always-on” MQQT client, running on the same VM, that subscribes to some of the MQTT topics from the broker, so that it can publish this data to a (remote) database.

Here is what I thought I could do:

1. SSH in to the Linux VM
2. Create a directory Install required packages / dependencies (node, mqtt, etc)
3. Create a JavaScript file (to subscribe to messages)
4. Run the JavaScript file
5. And everything works

Here’s where I actually am right now:

1. I SSH’d in to the VM
2. I navigated to where I wanted to created my directory
3. I get permission denied
4. I am stuck ☹

**Question 1:** Is my plan correct to run a JavaScript file from, within the VM correct / not possible

**Question 2:** Is there a specific location on the VM that I need to create my directory / file / run my script from?

If I get this running, I think I need to install ‘tmux’ so I can start the script, and close the SSH session and allow the script to keep running etc., but I will deal with that at a later stage – for now I just want to see if I can run my script from within the VM

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1:** It doesn't matter where you want to place your code. You can choose the VM or another one.

**Answer 2:** There isn't any specific locations to put your code there. For example you can put it under `/opt/` directory. You should have access to it, If not you can change your user to `root`.

**Suggestion:** It's better to create systemd service in Linux instead of using tmux. You can manage your app easily, please follow this [link](https://www.tecmint.com/create-systemd-service-linux/).